# VS2010, Web Performance Test, No hidden field detected on large response (>5MB)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web performance test which contains a request whose response is greater than 5MB, and the Extract Hidden Fields rule fails to find (necessary and required!) hidden fields in the response.

Response header contains

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Vary : Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
Cache-Control : private
Content-Type : text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date : Sat, 19 Feb 2011 15:24:38 GMT
Server : Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-AspNet-Version : 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET
```

Other than that and the response size, there is nothing remarkable about this scenario. In fact, this same test succeeds when a smaller data set is used.

I suspect the Web Performance Test framework is having issues parsing the "chunked" encoding or sheer volume of data.

Ahem, how can I obtain these required hidden fields from my response? Any hints or pointers would be much appreciated. ie resolutions, work arounds, converting auto-extraction to manual, etc.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you meaning `<input type='hidden' />` are being returned, and the values within are large (adding up to more than 5MB)?

Comment: @p.campbell, response body is entirely plain html, and describes a very large repeater control. the hidden fields that fail to extract are EventTarget fields (that are used downstream later in test. The extraction rule itself is an auto-generated rule created by the web test recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after much fussing around, [found this neat little article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsts/archive/2010/02/25/playing-back-a-recorded-web-test-with-vs-2008-fails-due-the-size-of-the-response.aspx), which indicates web test recorder captures ONLY first 1.5MB of data returned from request. In summary, the solution is to convert web test to a coded web test, and increase the test's `ResponseBodyCaptureLimit` to desired size.